# What are the differences between Mepiform and Mepiderm silicone plasters/tapes?

Tags: dermatology, scar-tissue-scars, plastic-surgery

What is the difference between silicone plasters/strips **Mepiform** and **Mepiderm**. What is better to use for a scar that is 1 month old? I want to use a silicone tape (for prevention of excessive formation of scars). Mepiderm is more expensive. Does this mean that it copes better with scars?